# IOKit/IOTypes.h file not found in ios

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, iokit

I am using private framework (IOKit) but I am getting this error now.

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issues - IOKit/IOTypes.h file not found
```

Please help

Comment: You should include IOKit/IOKit.h...

Comment: See if you can find IOKit/IOTypes.h in the file browser on the left and select it. Click up top right in the window to open the inspector pane on the right hand side of the window, and check 'target membership' for the file in question, make sure you have a tick in the box there

Comment: I didn't get your answer. Please describe in detail.

Comment: @Jef - Yes, Its not ticked, but I can't tick it as its disabled

Comment: Ok we need to work out why.  You need that tick.

Comment: @Dream, does your code already #import <IOKit/IOTypes.h>?  If so, why?  Is this your own Objective-C code, or is it code that you've included in your project, written by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok up top in the Xcode window is a series of little icons that open various panels within The window..

Open the one on left, this is the file browser..
Find IOKit in the list there, maybe inside the frameworks group.
It should have a folder (group in Xcode speak) called headers..
Browse inside headers and find IOTypes.h and select it.

Now go back up to those icons up top and open the right hand window, that's the inspector window..
Inside there is a box labelled target membership.
You need a tick in the box there for the file to be included in your build..

Then go to the file in question and up top add

```
#import <IOKit/IOTypes.h>
```

Comment: I can't tick in the target membership

Comment: What's your deployment target set to?  Maybe you're trying to support ios5 or whatever and this IOKit framework has deployment target of a higher version? Try setting yours to ios7 (even temporarily) and see if you can tick the box then..  Or maybe your need to add a flag for arc or something?

Comment: This works for public frameworks, but as the question tag suggests, this is a private API.  If you add the IOKit framework, you will not find this `Headers` folder ... it's private.

Comment: if its a private framework then I can't see how he can find the header in the browser ??

Comment: It **is** a private framework.  Whether he can or can't find the header in the file browser is not clear to me.  His responses have been extremely cryptic.  Unless he provided you additional information in a deleted comment, I wouldn't assume he's following everything you've said.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to

**a) Make sure the framework is copied in one of your build phases**

or

**b) forgot to import it `#import <IOKit/IOTypes.h>`**

Comment: This works for public frameworks, but as the question tag suggests, this is a private API.  The private headers are not included with the SDK for you to `#import` them.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Just:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/
```

Then type:

```
sudo ln -s Versions/A/IOKit
```

This should fix the issue for you

## Additional info for using private frameworks.

First you need to download Header files of "Private framework"
You can find them in
https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS6-Private-Frameworks

Then make imports like this

```
#import "GSEvent.h"
```

and make calls

```
GSEventLockDevice();
```

Comment: when I wrote this first statement in terminal, it gives - No such file or directory

Comment: If you are using Xcode5.1 try this "cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/"

Comment: same message - No such file or directory

Comment: I finally got the headers for IOKit,I have uploaded it to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7q6qislew58p0d/IOKit.zip drag and drop this headers to your project, and try #import "IOKit/IOTypes.h"

Comment: There's no (good) reason for your `sudo ln -s` command.  Not only will that command alone not fix his problem, but it's not even the best way to add a private framework to your project.  You add private frameworks the same way you add public ones.  You go to Project Target settings, Build Phases, and pick the private framework to link against.  You simply have to navigate to it manually on the filesystem, from within the file chooser popup.